# How to test expansion-panel in protractor

Tags: javascript, testing, protractor, expansion

I am trying to test e.g. this site in protractor:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/expansion-panel?file=main.ts

I want to click on the Panel1 and expand it.

Here is my code:

```
it('blabla', function() {
    browser.get('https://stackblitz.com/edit/expansion-panel?file=main.ts');
    browser.sleep(10000);
    element(by.css('.mat-expansion-panel-header.ng-tns-c2-1.ng-trigger.ng-trigger-expansionHeight')).click();
    browser.sleep(1000);
});
```

Comment: and what isn't working?

Comment: after click Panel1 it doesn't expand...

Comment: Did you try to click the parent-element of it? `element(by.css('mat-expansion-panel.mat-expansion-panel.ng-tns-c1-0)).click()` ... Also did your test succeed or fail? What does the log say?

Comment: works for me (Firefox 50). I can see the "content 1" panel under it.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using this helper function to open panels.

```
private async openExpansionPanel(position: number) {
  await element.all(by.css('mat-expansion-panel'))
    .get(position)
    .click();
}
```

If you're not using `async/await` you can just remove those.